# oracle dbms_pipe: message order sometimes disrupted (not first-in first-out)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-pro-c

For many years (somtetime before 2000) we have been using a package named HOSTP and a Pro*C executable named host_d in order to execute shell commands from PL/SQL. Both programs use DBMS_PIPE for communication.

Here is the central function of HOSTP code:

```
  FUNCTION hostd (command IN VARCHAR2,
                       hostuser IN VARCHAR2,
                       timeout1 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 300,
                       timeout2 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1200,
                       timeout3 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 240,
                       maxretry IN NUMBER DEFAULT 12)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    termiap      VARCHAR2(255);
    status       NUMBER;
    result       VARCHAR2(2000);
    command_code NUMBER;
    pipe_name    VARCHAR2(30);
    m_datei      utl_file.file_type;
    m_dutzend    pls_integer;

                 procedure p_debug (text_i in varchar) is
                 begin
                    m_datei := utl_file.fopen (hostuser || '/log',
                                               'hostd.' || to_char (sysdate, 'yyyymmdd') || '
.log',
                                               'a',
                                               4000);
                    utl_file.put_line (m_datei,
                                       pipe_name || ' ' || to_char (sysdate, 'hh24:mi:ss') ||
 ' ' || text_i);
                    utl_file.fclose (m_datei);
                 exception when others then dbms_output.put_line (sqlerrm);
                                            if utl_file.is_open (m_datei)
                                            then
                                               utl_file.fclose (m_datei);
                                            end if;
                 end p_debug;

  BEGIN
    pipe_name := DBMS_PIPE.UNIQUE_SESSION_NAME;
    DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE('HOSTD');
    DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE(pipe_name);
    DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE(command);
    DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE(hostuser);
    status := DBMS_PIPE.SEND_MESSAGE(hostuser || '_pipe', timeout1);
    p_debug ('S ' || status || ' ' || command || ' ' || to_char(timeout1) || ' ' || to_char(t
imeout2) || ' ' || to_char(timeout3) || ' ' || to_char(maxretry));
    IF status <> 0 THEN
      p_debug ('20020');
      termiap := termiap||' hostd-send-error: ' || status;
      termiap := termiap||' hostd-send-error: ' || status;
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20020,
        'hostd: Error while sending.  Status = ' || status);
    END IF;

 m_dutzend := 0;
 loop
    status := DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE(pipe_name, timeout3);
    p_debug ('A ' || status);

    -- ACK
    IF status = 0 THEN
       exit;
    else
      m_dutzend := m_dutzend + 1;
      if m_dutzend >= maxretry
      then
         p_debug ('20021 hostd: maxretry reached waiting for ACK');
         termiap := termiap||' hostd-receive-error: ' || status;
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20021,
           'hostd: Too many retries.
            Status = ' || status);
      end if;
    END IF;
 end loop;
    DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(result);
    IF result <> 'ACK' THEN
      p_debug ('20022 hostd: ACK not received, but ' || result);
    END IF;

    status := DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE(pipe_name, timeout2);

    IF status <> 0 THEN
      p_debug ('20023 hostd: waiting for done returns status ' || status);
      termiap := termiap||' hostd-receive-error: ' || status;
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20023,
        'hostd: Error while receiving.
         Status = ' || status);
    END IF;

    DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(result);
    IF result <> 'done' THEN
      p_debug ('R ' || status || ' ' || result || ' 20022');
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20022,
        'hostd: done not received, but ' || result);
      dbms_output.put_line ('20022 hostd: done not received, but ' || result);
      termiap := termiap||' hostd-receive-error: done not received';
    ELSE
      DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(command_code);
      DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(termiap);
      p_debug ('R ' || status || ' ' || result || ' ' || command_code || ' ' || replace (term
iap, chr (10), null));
      IF command_code <> 0 THEN
        IF (length(termiap)+length(command_code)+16 > 255) THEN
           termiap := substr(termiap, 1, 255 - length(command_code)-16);
        END IF;
        termiap := termiap||' execute-error: '|| command_code;
      END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN termiap;
  END hostd;
```

Host_d on the other side is a daemon written in Pro*C used to execute the shell commands and return results. I supply snippets of the most relevant parts here:

```
EXEC SQL EXECUTE
BEGIN
        :status := DBMS_PIPE.RECEIVE_MESSAGE(:xpipename, :RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);
        IF :status = 0 THEN
                DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(:command);
        END IF;
END;
END-EXEC;
```

....

```
EXEC SQL EXECUTE
BEGIN
        DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(:return_name);
        DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(:value);
        DBMS_PIPE.UNPACK_MESSAGE(:hostuid);
        END;
END-EXEC;
EXEC SQL EXECUTE
BEGIN
        DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE('ACK');
        :status := DBMS_PIPE.SEND_MESSAGE(:return_name);
END;
END-EXEC;
```

...

```
EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
```

... (doing a fork() here)

```
/* reconnect to Oracle as parent & child - can we avoid this as parent? (AR 060207) */
EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR DO connect_error();
EXEC SQL CONNECT :uid;
EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR DO sql_error();
```

... (in the child)

```
EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR DO sql_error();
EXEC SQL EXECUTE
BEGIN
DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE('done');
DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE(:exitstat);
DBMS_PIPE.PACK_MESSAGE(:xtermiap);
:status := DBMS_PIPE.SEND_MESSAGE(:return_name);
END;
END-EXEC;
if (status != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "[%s] Hostd error while responding to hostd command., %s", tstr(), hostdcom);
        fprintf (stderr, "  status: %d, errno: %d (%s)\n", status, errno, strerror(errno));
}
EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
exit(0);
```

Most of the requests are ok (this mechanism has been under heavy use from >= 10 applications in its basic form for two decades).

BUT sometimes we get this in the logs of HOSTP:

```
root@vmkern $ grep 080DA38D0001 <logfile>
ORA$PIPE$080DA38D0001 13:58:33 S 0 <request> 300 1200 240 12
ORA$PIPE$080DA38D0001 13:58:33 A 0
ORA$PIPE$080DA38D0001 13:58:33 20022 hostd: ACK not received, but done
ORA$PIPE$080DA38D0001 13:58:33 R 0 ACK 20022
```

Comparing above code of HOSTP and this log it looks very much as if the ACK and the DONE messages from host_d are sent to HOSTP in the wrong order.

Comment: This is a long post and a lot of code but no actual question. Exactly what are you expecting of us?

Comment: Sorry about not including a question. I'd like to find out why the message order gets corrupted sometimes and fix that if possible. So any hint on tracing what happens within the dbms_pipe package would be greatly appreciated. Otherwise I'd like to know if anyone has had similar issues. And, finally, I'd like to discuss possibilities on how to avoid and/or work around this problem